# Performance of boost::signals2

Tags: c++, multithreading, signals, slots

I'm switching from xlobjects to boost::signals2 as my signal/slot framework in the hope that the establishment of connections, threir removal, signal emission, etc is thread-safe. I'm not interested in inter-thread signal emission at all.

So the simple question is: is boost::signals2 thread safe in the way that, for instance, two or more threads can make a connection on the same signal?

Also, does boost::signals2 incur a performance penalty compared to xlobjects? This is not important as the application doesn't rely heavily on signals/slots, but I'd like to know nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe all the answers you need regarding thread safety in boost.signal are in [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/signals2/thread-safety.html) (short answer : yes, boost:signals2 is thread safe). Regarding performance, I guess thread-safety comes at a cost, but there's only one way to be sure : benchmark !

Answer (score 3):

boost signals2 is thread safe.

but if for some reason you need extra performance, and can guarantee the single thread access, there is a dummy mutex in the signals2 library that will be a lot faster than a real mutex.